# Timeout error during full crawling in sharepoint 2013

Tags: crawling, time-out

In SharePoint 2013 Production, I am trying to do full crawl. However, crawling is too slow and crawl only few items in 1 hour. Log gives below error:-

```
 CManagedSqlSession::InitBulkInsert m_ManagedSqlSession->InitBulkInsert fails    
 with Error 0x80131509 Description 'Timeout expired.  The timeout period    
 elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have 
 occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was 
 reached.' Message 'Unknown error 0x80131509'
```

I have restarted SharePoint search services application, restarted SharePoint server search 15 service, checked web application's pool a/c having access on content DB. Is there anything I am missing in configuration?

I have server:-
WFE-2, Application server-3, DB-1 (SQL server 2012/R2), Project server-1

Answer (score 0):

for me, Look like a connection problem with Database server. You can try couple of things;

- You can try to increase the [connection to database timeout value](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263314.aspx) running the below command

  stsadm -o setproperty -pn database-connection-timeout -pv 60
- Make sure  Database Engine is listening on dynamic ports

Please check more troubleshooting steps here( number 8 and 9)
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6545.sharepoint-2013-troubleshooting-cannot-connect-to-the-configuration-database.aspx